# Display full content of multiple lines of text column in list view when Append is enabled

Tags: 2010, list-view, multiple-lines-of-text, append-changes

Is it possible to display the full content of multiple lines of text column in list view when append is enabled?

Right now it shows "Views Entries..." click on which i can view the column data.